# AngularJS - Open new window with $window and display shared data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-click on one of my pages that, when the user clicks, I want to set the specific site for that selection and use it in a new html page.  I have tried a bunch of different things (using $rootscope, $rootscope.$broadcast, adding property to service, etc) and I can't get it to display in the new page.  Values that have been set in the controller prior to the ng-click function call I can see, but the value I am trying to set during the ng-click is not accessible on the new page....on the base page I can see the selection.

These pages are sharing the same controller.

I am sure I am doing something wrong, I just cant for the life of me figure out what it is.

Function exposed to base site:

```
//Get specific Site
$scope.getSiteInfo = function (site) {
    $scope.siteInfo = site;

    $window.open('Base/SiteInfo', 'SiteInformation');


}
```

Example html ng-click (console log shows that I am getting the site info)

```
                      <tbody>
                            <tr data-ng-repeat="site in criticalSites">
                                <td data-ng-click="getSiteInfo(site)">{{site.SystemName}}</td>
                                <td>{{site.SystemName}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is a *single page* application framework. Opening a different window (or a different page) just for showing information is something that angular isn't meant to do. You can't pass objects or share scopes between two pages.

Instead of using `window.open`, you should use a CSS-based dialog. It's simpler, looks better, and works better with Angular. I recommend to use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: Hi Alon thanks for your response.  By CSS-based dialog I assume you mean something like a modal in bootstrap?